# Why can I add extensions methods to the string class but not to DateTime?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

If I make a method like this:

```
public static void ExtMethod(this string);
```

it will show up if I invoke it like so:

```
string str = "";
str.ExtMethod();
```

but if I did this:

```
public static void ExtMethod(this DateTime);
```

this doesn't work:

```
DateTime date;
date.ExtMethod();
```

I have to call it like this:

```
ExtMethod(date);
```

So why can I make an extension method for string but not for DateTime?

Comment: What is the error message? What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It should work. Are you missing a using directive for the namespace of your extension class?

Comment: Neither of your current extension methods would compile, as you haven't provided a name for the parameter. Note that assuming the error message you're seeing is actually about definite assignment (as per kordiseps' answer) you'd see the same thing for your string extension method if you didn't assign an initial value to the variable.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the shown sample methods are abbreviated to the signature, they also don't have a body.

Comment: @mummy Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @Steeeve: The problem with not showing a complete example (and not even showing the error message) is that it's not clear which problems are just a typo and which problems are actually in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date variable is not assigned. You need to assign some value.
e.g.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;//or some value else
date.ExtMethod();
```

instead of

```
DateTime date;
date.ExtMethod();
```

Comment: D'oh! Yeah, that's me problem. I intuitively wanted to use it like `DateTime.ExtMethod()` but that's not an extension method, thanks!